# Determining which elements of a matrix group form a one-parameter subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, proof-explanation

We have just learned about one-parameter subgroups in my Algebra class and I am not sure if I am approaching the following proof in the right way.

> **Problem Statement**: Let $G$ be a group of real matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} x && y \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix}$ with $x>0$.
>
> > a) Determine the matrices $A$ such that $e^{tA}$ is a one-parameter group in $G$.
> >
> > b) Compute $e^{tA}$ explicitly for the matrices in (a).
> >
> > c) Make a drawing showing some one-parameter subgroups in the xy-plane.

So for a) I must show that $e^{(s+t)A}=e^{sA}e^{tA}$ in order to be a one-parameter subgroup, correct? So I thought to compute the first few terms of the expansion for each of these, to determine which matrices worked, but this may be too complicated.

I have

$$e^{(t+s)A}=I+(s+t)A+\frac{(s^2+2st+t^2)}{2}A^2+...$$
$$e^{sA}e^{tA}=I+(s+t)A+\frac{(s^2+2st+t^2)}{2}A^2+\frac{(s^2t+st^2)}{2}A^3+\frac{(s^2t^2)}{4}A^4+...$$

(I mutlplied the first 3 terms of $e^{sA}$ by the first 3 terms of $e^{tA}$, is that what I should be doing?)

So should I be choosing matrices such that $A^3,A^4=\mathbf{0}$? I am not thinking that my strategy is correct, because $$A^n=\begin{bmatrix} x^n && x^ny+x^{n-1}y+...+xy+y \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ and I believe I would be left with very few matrices which form a one-parameter subgroup if $A^3,A^4=\mathbf{0}$ must hold.

Any advice on how I should be approaching a)? I should be able to figure out b) once I finish a). Then for c), once I compute $e^{tA}$ explicitly, should I be drawing points on the plane after I determine the appropriate values for $x,y$? I am also not quite sure how to approach this part.

Any strategies/suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a typo and you are looking for the matrices $A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ for which $e^{tA}$ is a one-parameter subgroup in $G$. Note that for any matrix $A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, the family $e^{tA}$ is a one-parameter subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ (we always have $e^{(t+s)A} = e^{tA}e^{sA}$ as can be checked by expanding the power series). The question is for which matrices $A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, the image $e^{tA}$ lands inside the group $G$.

Assume that $A \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that for $\alpha_A(t) := e^{tA}$ we have $\alpha(t) \in G$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Writing

$$ \alpha_A(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x(t) & y(t) \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

we have

$$ \dot{\alpha}_A(0) = A = \begin{pmatrix} \dot{x}(0) & \dot{y}(0) \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

so this suggests that for matrices of the form

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

the one-parameter subgroups $\alpha_A(t)$ will land inside $G$. You can check this directly by computing $\alpha_A(t) = e^{tA}$ (there will be two cases - where $a \neq 0$ and when $a = 0$ (in which case $A$ is nilpotent)).

Comment: Oh I see, so we are looking for matrices $A$ such that $e^{tA}$ is within the group. But I am confused why in your example, $\alpha_A(0)$ turns the $1$ in index $2,2$ to a $0$? Also why does $t=0$ determine which matrices work?I worked with matrix exponentials in my ODE II class, but I think I have been a little confused about what makes something a one-parameter subgroup. It makes more sense now.  **EDIT**: Oh, does it turns it to a zero because you are multiplying the matrix entire matrix by $t^i=0$?

Comment: We should have $\alpha_A(0) = e^{0 \cdot A} = e^{0_{2 \times 2}} = I_{2 \times 2}$ - the $(2,2)$ index should be one, not zero. A one-parameter subgroup is usually defined to be a smooth group homomorphism $\alpha \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow G$ so $\alpha_A(0)$ should always be the identity element of $G$. It turns out that if $G$ sits inside $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ then one parameter subgroups can be always described as $\alpha(t) = e^{tA}$ for a certain subspace of $A$'s. What I wrote only showed that a necessary condition for $e^{tA}$ to be a one-parameter subgroup of $G$

Comment: is that $A$ has the form above, but one can show that indeed these are one-parameter subgroups and in fact, these are the only possible one-parameter subgroups.